# Xcode8 Controllers are Grey which are designed in Xcode 7 with size classes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, storyboard

I am making my iOS Application Compatible with iPad.I have designed the UI of my Application with Xcode 7 with size classes which is more specifically designed for iPhone, Now i have to upgrade it to support iPad also.

Now with Xcode 8 when i select iPad from Storyboard with Device Pan then most of the controller are Greyed i.e. those controllers are not showing on iPad on the device also and on the Storyboard also. Please check the screenshot for that

[image]

I know the reason why they greyed out, because they are designed with size classes for a different size.

**Now my question is**, is it possible somehow to use this controller for iPad without Redesigning the UI and updating the Auto layouts, as of now i am not seeing any way to make this controllers available for iPad.

Also i have tried with a way but i think that will be very long, I have to delete this controllers and then add it back and set the layouts again.

Also another way would be design separate storyboard.

So please suggest me what will be a better solution to overcome from this.

Thanks

Comment: See the thing is.. if you want to make it working with iPad, you need to remove your size classes options. Without changing it, won't work on iPad.

Comment: @Sharpkits But with xcode8 there is no option of Size Classes, also i have made all the storyboards compatible with Xcode8 if i want to use it on xcode7 then i need to disable that

Comment: Its like a flaw in the design i believe. This is how close i'm able to understand it. What you need to do is remove any leftovers after the compatibility conversion by Xcode 8. How you can do it is, answering below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after compatibility conversion to Xcode 8, if still it doesn't seem to work, then you need to check if there are any leftovers like below:

If you want to make sure it works with any width and height, find the constraint:

[image]

and remove it by clicking on the `x`, leaving only `installed` checked:

[image]

That should solve it for Xcode 8.

Comment: after doing this, still i need to set the layout from beginning.

Comment: Then i'm afraid, can't help any further because, that is an issue with Xcode's Compatibility conversion for Autolayout.. in some cases all the controls come at the centre, regardless of the constraints.

Comment: I think i have to go with this, thanks for your help (y)